# Ignore compile error - CREATE PROCEDURE with body regardless

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

Is there a way to force SQL Server 2008R2 to create a stored procedure which includes a linked server query where the linked server does not exist, or does exist but without a data source.

I am fully aware how daft this sounds but it is company policy to deploy all database objects (inc. SPs) to all databases on all servers. However in this case I am unable to create the linked server at all servers.

The error returned is

> Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TestLinkedSever, Line 23 The
>   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "LinkedServer" does not
>   contain the table ""Database"."dbo"."table"". The table either does
>   not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

Comment: Not every piece of stupidity can be counteracted by technology. You need to report back that what they want isn't practical (short of e.g. @SpectralGhost's answer of effectively turning it all into strings interpreted at runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest making the stored procedure dynamic SQL based and store the server name in a table. I've been involved in projects where we had to fix linked server names because company standards enforced a name change on upgrade. It's not fun.